# After js validation and redir data is lost and not avalibale for php validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, http-post, data-loss

I can't figure out why it is not working.

I have simple form and want to validate in client side with simple xmlrequest redirect to other page, do there server validation and work with validated parameter.

All in js vanilla and pure PHP.

html:

```
<form  action=""  novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off"  id="name-group">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="number">*Number:</label>
      <input value="" type="text" name="number" id="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

js validation:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let number = document.getElementById("number").value;

    let numberRegex = "^[0-9]$";
    let errorMsg = '';
    if (number.match(numberRegex)) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let params = "number=" + number;
        xhr.open("POST", './uploadValidation.php',true)
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        // xhr.onload = function () {
        // }
        xhr.send(encodeURI(params));
        window.location.assign('./uploadValidation.php')
    } else {
        errorMsg = 'required number field';
    }
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = errorMsg
});
```

After this I want to redirect to other page and do server validation

```
<?php

//errors
$errors = [
    'number' => '',
];
var_dump($_POST);
//validation
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $number = htmlentities(trim($_POST['number']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    echo true;

    //check for error in userName field
    if (!$number || mb_strlen($number) < 1) {
        $form_valid = false;
        $errors['number'] = '*required field';
    }
}

?>
```

And the data is lost `$_POST['number']` is not available.

Please can someone explain to me why it is not working and how to fix?

**EDIT:** I want to get input from user in first page and after js and PHP validation work with the input in second page.in my case add dynamically inputs field (the number of fields = number from first user input).

Comment: Why are you redirecting to the URL that you use for AJAX validation?

Comment: You can't use `window.location` to post a form, it just does simple page load of the given URL. Since this is an event listener, I think you can just return `true` to continue the form submit event. But why are you doing this instead of just using HTML validation. `<input value="" type="number" name="number" id="number" class="form-control" required="required"/>`.

Comment: on first page I want user to enter the number and validate with js (he can enter anything). and on the second page after server validation to work with the input ,for my case built number of inputs that I got from first page.@Barmar